# PHP/MYSQL changing username and password

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my appserv. I am trying to log in to create an SQL database with username and password, however it does not work.

This is the `config.inc.php` excerpt:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'http';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'albert';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '1234';
```

Note that I have changed my localhost to 127.0.0.1 even with 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin is not working too.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1';
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'albert'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your mysql username, password database name or host is wrong

Comment: if your phpMyAdmin is not working too, it seems to be a configuration problem with your server. later "Access Denied" is a case of Wrong Credentials... you need to verify them.

Answer (score 0):

That is the MySQL error message for failed authentication. Either your username or password is incorrect. If you have cpanel or some kind of management tool, make sure you have the correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

As per mentioned Server login credentials is wrong thats why Display Access denied for user.

Thanks,
JAY